# The wordpress Read More doesn't work, it displays the full content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display some post by ID in WordPress. My problem is that when I display the content (not with the_content()) the read more tag doesn't word, it displays the full content.

I didn't use the loop and the the_content function, i tried this way:

```
echo get_post_field('post_content', $id);
```

Is there any way to display with this method?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
```